# Merge two OccupancyGridMaps

Tags: ros, navigation, nav-msgs, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

as the topic says: I want to merge/combine two OccupancyGridMaps.

The conditions:
I recieve two messages (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid) by two services. These two maps have the same resolution, but different postions and size (orientation can be omitted).

My question:
Is there an easy way to combine/overlay these maps and build a new map out of these? Or do I have to do this the hard way?

Kind regards, tiko

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29147/merge-two-occupancygridmaps/) by [tiko](https://answers.ros.org/users/1659/tiko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The occupancy_grid_utils package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/occupancy_grid_utils) provides a "union of grids" operation.

---

Originally posted by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) with karma: 1479 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My advice: convert them to images, work as images, and then convert back. That is, build an OpenCV 8-bit unsigned image for each map, then rotate and translate one appropriately, and then add them together in image space, and switch back to an OccupancyGrid.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1